# Android view pager with page indicator

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-view, viewpagerindicator, activity-indicator

I need to get page indicator in the view pager file with images. Here is my code.

```
public class IndicatorActivity extends Activity {


 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
            ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            TitlePageIndicator indicator = (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicat);
            indicator.setViewPager( myPager );
    }
}
```

In this code, i got an error in  `TitlePageIndicator indicator = (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicat);` as `TitlePageIndicator cannot be resolved to a type`. What is this error. How can I resolve it?

here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />
    <com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicat"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What code do I need to write in the `TitlePageIndicator`?
**I want to do this without using fragments**.

Me also created a class such as:

```
class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

     private static Integer[] titles = new Integer[] 
                { 
        R.drawable.jk,R.drawable.lm,R.drawable.no
                };

    public int getCount() {
            return 3;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view;
            ImageView iv;

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first, null);

            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                iv.setImageResource(titles[position]);
                    break;
            case 1:
                iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                iv.setImageResource(titles[position]);
                    break;
            case 2:
                 iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                iv.setImageResource(titles[position]);
                    break;
            }
            return view;
    }

    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
            ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

    }



    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
            return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

    }

}
```

Did I want to do anything more than this class?

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Did you import `com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator`?  If you're working in Eclipse, try pressing Ctrl+Shif+O.

Comment: I am working in eclipse only. I did that, but that is not getting import into the program..

Comment: Is their any other way for importing that?

Comment: Just type `import com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator` on the second line of the file (before `public class ...`).  Provided you set up your libraries correctly, it will work.

Comment: The import com.viewpagerindicator cannot be resolved....this is the error came when i did like that...Did i want to create any class named TitlePageIndicator?

Comment: is there any other way for importing that into my class?

Comment: There is no need for 3rd party code nor any kind of manual hacks. A TabLayout is the perfect widget to build a page-indicator.

Please, take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44231881/1850606

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are a few things you need to do:

1-Download the [library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) if you haven't already done that.

2- Import into Eclipse.

3- Set you project to use the library:
Project-> Properties -> Android -> Scroll down to Library section, click *Add...* and select viewpagerindicator.

4- Now you should be able to import `com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator`.

Now about implementing this without using fragments:

In the sample that comes with *viewpagerindicatior*, you can see that the library is being used with a `ViewPager` which has a `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

But in fact the library itself is `Fragment` independant. It just needs a `ViewPager`.
So just use a `PagerAdapter` instead of a `FragmentPagerAdapter` and you're good to go.

Comment: I created a class using PageAdapter. Pls check my program. I updated that also...and please help me now...

Comment: i set the  library as you told. But there is no viewpagerindicator in the  Project-> Properties -> Android -> Scroll down to Library section, click Add...

Comment: did i want to create any class in the name of TitlePageIndicator or any other class??

Comment: Hey benito i am using the same lib for three tabs each having a list view with same arraylist set to there adapters , i want if i checked a checkbox in any one of the list among three tabs (i am updating values in db and my list) other two should reflect changes, please help me on this. you can find my question here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314600/listview-not-refreshing-in-fragment-with-viewpager-tabs

Answer (score 54):

**UPDATE:** 22/03/2017

main fragment layout:

```
       <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/page_group"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_help_container"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/page1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/page2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/page3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </FrameLayout>
```

set up view and event on your fragment like this:

```
        mViewPaper = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mViewPaper.setAdapter(adapder);

        mPageGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.page_group);
        mPageGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        mViewPaper.addOnPageChangeListener(this);

       *************************************************
       *************************************************

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // when current page change -> update radio button state
        int radioButtonId = mPageGroup.getChildAt(position).getId();
        mPageGroup.check(radioButtonId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedId) {
        // when checked radio button -> update current page
        RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton)radioGroup.findViewById(checkedId);
        // get index of checked radio button
        int index = radioGroup.indexOfChild(checkedRadioButton);

        // update current page
        mViewPaper.setCurrentItem(index), true);
    }
```

custom checkbox state: [Custom checkbox image android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965484/custom-checkbox-image-android)

Viewpager tutorial: http://architects.dzone.com/articles/android-tutorial-using

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, doesn't need external libraries! i just extended this idea using a simple custom view to display the dots instead of the radios. Thanx alot!

Comment: @j.c Could you please help me get a custom radio button. I tried and only could change the background but the dots and the outline remains on top of it every time

Comment: `setOnPageChangeListener` is deprecated. Use `addOnPageChangeListener` instead.

Answer (score 10):

I know this has already been answered, but for anybody looking for a simple, no-frills implementation of a ViewPager indicator, I've implemented one that I've open sourced. For anyone finding Jake Wharton's version a bit complex for their needs, have a look at  https://github.com/jarrodrobins/SimpleViewPagerIndicator.

Comment: @JRod tried your library, but my app keeps crashing on the line  ImageView item = items.get(i); in the setCurrentItem() method when i try swiping views.

Answer (score 5):

I have also used the SimpleViewPagerIndicator from @JROD. It also crashes as described by @manuelJ.

According to his documentation:

```
SimpleViewPagerIndicator pageIndicator = (SimpleViewPagerIndicator) findViewById(R.id.page_indicator);
pageIndicator.setViewPager(pager);
```

Make sure you add this line as well:

```
pageIndicator.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

It crashes with an array out of bounds exception because the SimpleViewPagerIndicator is not getting instantiated properly and the items are empty. Calling the notifyDataSetChanged results in all the values being set properly or rather reset properly.

Answer (score 2):

Just an improvement to the nice answer given by @vuhung3990.
I implemented the solution and works great but if I touch one radio button it will be selected and nothing happens.

I suggest to also change page when a radio button is tapped. To do this, simply add a listener to the radioGroup:

```
mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);    
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch (checkedId) {
                    case R.id.radioButton :
                        mPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
                        break;
                    case R.id.radioButton2 :
                        mPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
                        break;
                    case R.id.radioButton3 :
                        mPager.setCurrentItem(2, true);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: thank you, i will update my answer but have litte different

Answer (score 1):

you have to do following:

1-Download the full project from here https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator
[ViewPager Indicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator)
2- Import into the Eclipse.

After importing if you want to make following type of screen then follow below steps -

[image: Screen Shot]

change in

**Sample circles Default**

```
  package com.viewpagerindicator.sample;
  import android.os.Bundle;  
  import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
  import com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator;

  public class SampleCirclesDefault extends BaseSampleActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_circles);

    mAdapter = new TestFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
  //  mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(SampleCirclesDefault.this);
    mPager.setAdapter(adapter);


    mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
  }
}
```

**ImageAdapter**

```
 package com.viewpagerindicator.sample;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
 import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
 private Context mContext;

 private Integer[] mImageIds = { R.drawable.about1, R.drawable.about2,
        R.drawable.about3, R.drawable.about4, R.drawable.about5,
        R.drawable.about6, R.drawable.about7

 };

 public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
 }

 public int getCount() {
    return mImageIds.length;
 }

 public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
 }

 public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
 }

 @Override
 public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_view, null);

    ImageView view_image = (ImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.view_image);
    TextView description = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.description);

    view_image.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
    view_image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    description.setText("The natural habitat of the Niligiri tahr,Rajamala          Rajamala is 2695 Mts above sea level"
        + "The natural habitat of the Niligiri tahr,Rajamala Rajamala is 2695 Mts above sea level"
                    + "The natural habitat of the Niligiri tahr,Rajamala Rajamala is 2695 Mts above sea level");

    ((ViewPager) container).addView(convertView, 0);

    return convertView;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((View) object);
 }

 @Override
 public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ViewGroup) object);
 }
}
```

**gallery_view.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/about_bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/about_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/about_layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".4"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/view_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:background="@drawable/about1">
     </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/about_layout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".6"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SIGNATURE LANDMARK OF MALAYSIA-SINGAPORE CAUSEWAY"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance" />


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="false"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="TextView" />

            </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can create a Linear layout containing an array of TextView (mDots).
To represent the textView as Dots provide this HTML source in your code .
refer my code .
I got this information from Youtube Channel TVAC Studio .
here the code : `

```
    addDotsIndicator(0);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewListener);
}

public void addDotsIndicator(int position)
{
        mDots = new TextView[5];
        mDotLayout.removeAllViews();

        for (int i = 0; i<mDots.length ; i++)
        {
             mDots[i]=new TextView(this);
             mDots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));            //HTML for dots
             mDots[i].setTextSize(35);
             mDots[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

             mDotLayout.addView(mDots[i]);
        }

        if(mDots.length>0)
        {
            mDots[position].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
        }
}

ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int 
   positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        addDotsIndicator(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
};`
```