# How to import ViewPagerIndicator library in Eclipse

Tags: android, android-intent, view, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I referred this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316931/android-view-pager-with-page-indicator).

As they mentioned, I download it as a zip file and tried to import the library project into Eclipse, but I can't. Instead I get a message "No files to import". How to overcome this?

Answer (score 11):

Normally the problem is that you have an existing project called "library" in your workspace, you need to rename it and try to "import from existing code" again.

Another option is

1. In the project root directory, run mvn eclipse:clean
2. Then run mvn eclipse:eclipse  to build .classpath and .project files

Hope it works.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use the ViewPagerIndicator as a library in your project. You have import the ViewPagerIndicator as a project, and then reference it in your project.

Comment: Yes , but i tried to import ViewPageIndicater as a project, but i cant, theres an Message "No projects found to import"

Comment: when you go import...then choose Android->Existing Android Code Into Workspace. You also have to extract the ZIP file first.

Comment: Yeah just now i tried , again thers an error message box showing  "Case Variant Exists" is there any other way?

Comment: try this: [link](http://www.buzztouch.com/forum/thread.php?tid=ABDA820A66DC54F&status=..)
and this:
[link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29796)

Answer (score 0):

You can choose between two possibilities:

1. Copy the library source folder into your android project source folder.
2. If you won't the library as an own library project, follow these steps:

Package Explorer > New > Project ... > Choose "Android > Android Project from Existing Code" > Select unzipped Lib Folder