# How to include GitHub library to your existing Android project in eclipse

Tags: android, import, github

I want to include [this](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker/tree/master/library) library from github to my existing project, I am using eclipse.
Is there any tutorial on how to do this? I am new to android and java development so any step by step help would be great!

note:
I have an Egit plugin installed in eclipse.

---

Image of the screen when I try to Import the library from the unziped file I have downloaded from the github page:
[image]

---

Also after importing the library as suggested below a library folder created in my Package Explorer but here is what I get:
[image]

---

I have now the library in the eclipse Package explorer, and now I want to add it to my project, so I Right-Click on the existing project and choose properties. Under Android liabrary i click ok and choose the library than ok, nothing happens!

Comment: do you want to add .jar file only or whole project as library?

Comment: It is an Android library project, simply download the source, import and setup it in Eclipse, then [reference it in your own project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject).

Comment: It also has to be imported in same workspace as your project .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same problem as yours, please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858675/how-to-import-viewpagerindicator-library-in-eclipse/14435370#14435370) , hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project -> properties -> Android -> Add. There you can hose a library.

[image]

Comment: after I have imported the library I am getting this (have added an image to the question).

Comment: You can't import the lib because you have an other project (library presumably) who's name is the name is also "library". Right click on that other project -> refactor -> rename.

Comment: did it, but still not working. If you could do a step by step process from the github project download to implementation it would be great (I know it is to much to ask for).

Comment: Was there an other project with the same name("library") in your **workspace**?

Comment: yes, but it was the project that I have imported from the github I wanted

Comment: Here is what I have done step by step: 1. downloaded the zip file from github. 2. unzipped it. 3. clicked right mouse button on my project folder and than clicked android -> Existing android code Into Workspace -> next. 4.  Root Directory: C:\Users\Vlad\Desktop\android-numberpicker-master. 5. Finish 6. A SampleActivity project created.

Comment: Hmmm so you could import the sample project but not the lib? Or what is your problem?

Comment: Yes, the import doesn't recognize the lib

Comment: Is the lib imported? Or is it just the sample?

Comment: @VladIoffe: import `C:\Users\Vlad\Desktop\android-numberpicker-master\library` instead.

Comment: says to give at least one project

Answer (score 0):

Extract the zip,

> Right click in your workspace -> Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code Into
>   Workspace -> give path of that project/library

Done.

Comment: there is no Android option on right click in the workspace, only Android tools

Comment: I am getting this error. (have added an image in the question)