# Including library to android project

Tags: android, eclipse, import, github, shared-libraries

I have downloaded a library from github, and imported it as android project.
In this library that called Library under preferences -> Android I have set it as a library project as seen bellow:
[image]

Now I want to add this library to my Android project that called test. So I Right-Click on it and than preferences -> Android, after that I click add... and choose the library, as seen below:
[image]
Than I hit ok and apply and ok again. Nothing happens. After that I click again Right-Click on my project and than preferences -> Android and here is what I see:
[image]

What should I do to make it work fine?
The github project link is [here](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker).

Comment: Did you out the .jar required by the library in your `libs` directory?

Comment: Didn't you already ask this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891715/how-to-include-github-library-to-your-existing-android-project-in-eclipse

Comment: It is the same library different problem, may I say more specific.

Comment: Try restarting Eclipse. Eclipse sometimes gets into a state where it cannot add a new library project.

Comment: have restarted it, even the computer

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the project from the git and checked it,The **.project** file for eclipse is missing.

My solution would be create a new project and use these resources

Comment: What do you mean by use as resource ?