# How to use github projects in android

Tags: android, github

I want to use [this](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview) github project in my existing android app. Could anyone elaborate how to do that ?

Comment: **Download** the zip, **unzip** it, **import** the project. Done.

Comment: Read the usage section of the given link...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1 : Download Zip file

Step 2 : unzip Downloaded file

Step 3 : Open Eclipse New->Android Project->Android Project from existing source->
         Browse downloaded project

Step : 4 Right click project folder Go Properties->Android-> and make this project as library

Step : in your project go properties-> android-> Add Library -> and select library project which you import

Step 5 : Now re-build your project

Now .You able to used all class as library in your existing project

For more information see [How to include GitHub library to your existing Android project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891715/how-to-include-github-library-to-your-existing-android-project-in-eclipse) thread