# Using socket.io client library with Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to use this library in my android app:

https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client

But I don't know how can I import library to my app.Can you explain this ?

(I am using eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click your `project -> properties -> Android -> Add`.
There you can add the library.

[image]

**NOTE:** There should not be another project with the same name(library presumably) in your 
          workspace.

Also check - [How to include GitHub library to your existing Android project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891715/how-to-include-github-library-to-your-existing-android-project-in-eclipse).

**UPDATE:**

> I copied these files to libs folder.But still not showing in the list.

*Steps to import the library project in detail -*

- Download the project from
  https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client.
- Unzip the project into the same workspace where your current
  application workspace is.
- Import the project in eclipse.
- Right click the project and go to `project -> properties -> Android`
  .
- Tick the checkbox for `Is Library`.
- Go to your application in eclipse.
- Right click your `application -> properties -> Android -> Add`
- Now you will see the project in the list where you can add it.

Comment: I can't see in the list.I imported to workspace but I can't see in the library list.Here you can see:http://prntscr.com/475173

Comment: No, you first need to put your `socket.io client library` into your project workspace libs folder where your other jar files exists. Then you follow the above instructions to import.

Comment: Which files I have to copy ? I copied socket.io folder to project root folder but not worked.

Comment: You have to copy `WebSocket.jar` and `json-org.jar` from this url - https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client/tree/master/libs

Comment: I copied these files to libs folder.But still not showing in the list.

Comment: Didn't understood what do you mean by not showing ? The copied files are already there in your project. You just need to import them now by `project -> properties -> Android -> Add`.

Comment: Here you can see:http://prntscr.com/4754vj What is wrong ?

Comment: OK, check my detailed updated answer.

Comment: But there is no android tab : http://prntscr.com/4759p3

Comment: You need to import this project as a `Import -> Existing Android Code into Workspace` just like you normally do for any android project that you create from scratch. Meaning import like android project to see Android Tab.

Comment: I tried but I can't import as an android project.http://prntscr.com/475d1b

Comment: ok then first do `Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace` and then import to your application's workspace. Remember to tick mark `Copy Projects into Workspace` in the `Import Projects` wizard.

Comment: I tried but same result,I can't see in the library list.

Comment: After copying the project into your workspace, you need to follow `Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace` and then import it. It is working in my system.

Comment: It is importing but I can't add as a library to my project.That is the problem

Comment: Because this is not the android project to import. As I said, once you created the new project with any name then just copy all the files from your `socket.io-java-client` project folder to that new project folder. This hack will work. I did the same. See the image in my answer.

Comment: To be particular, just copy the libs and src folder of your socket project to the new project.