# implement swiping images when user opens our app first time

Tags: android

Below is the images of Google drive introductory image.
Its purpose is to let the user know what our app does or what you can do with it.
Whenever user install app and opens it first time.. user would see this.
after then it will not appear.

So my question is, can anyone tell me how can we implement this in our app? 
any tutorial or example? or just information how can i do it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I suggest you to use this library https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: @MicheleLacorte .. i understand but there would be a way to implement without library.. i want to do it by myself... also .. this is viewpager.. so i guess its used for swipping tabs only.. ..

Comment: Try to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316931/android-view-pager-with-page-indicator

Answer (score 1):

I see that you want to do without a library. I used [AndroidImageSlider](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider). You should check it out, it can give you some ideas of how to do by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I found this library [AppIntro](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro) should be what you mean , it's all well explained in the documentation, it is easy to implement, I hope to be as helpful.

**[Video Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OlAugnH3jFY&feature=youtu.be)**

**Image example:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Okay its great, but how are they doing it? Are they simply using Fragments in ViewPager to show the pages? and customize the next and down level buttons?

Comment: is simply an Activity that extends AppIntro, in the documentation it's explained very well, you must not do is tell you how many slides are , images and other things , he does everything for the rest! :D

Comment: No i understood that.... but i mean if we don't want to use library and if i want to implement it by myself, then simply they customized the Fragments in ViewPager right?- i think simple concept is that to implement welcome slides , is that so?

Comment: Yes! @AjayP.Prajapati

Comment: alright thanks..  one up for you.. thanks brother... i appreciate it